# Good way to call render() method in backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Long time back I was sort of convinced that `render()` is prerogative of view itself and not parent view's concern.

However lately I read about `delegateEvents` in backbone and had mixed feeling about how I implemented. So far everywhere I was calling `render()` method within `initialize` method.

I have not done exhaustive testing or found an use case of where I may face a problem. However it gives me feeling of potential problem lurking with the way I have done.

Could you please share your experience? What are the problems with calling `render()` method within `initialize`? And how would you do it?

Is parent dictating child where to and when to render itself r is it still within the boundaries of SoC (separation of concern)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I see about 3 different scenarios for rendering the first 2 are a the render-within parent,

```
// parent view's render
render: function() {
  var child = new ChildView({el: this.$('.foo'), model: bar, ...});
  this.$el.append(child.render().el);
}
```

which is basically the case where the parent dictates where or when the child is rendered, and the render-within-itself,

```
// parent view's render
render: function() {
  var child = new ChildView({el: this.$('.foo'), model: bar, ...});
  this.$el.append(child.el);
}

// child view's initialize
initialize: function() {
  ...
  this.render();
}
```

which is the case where the child view dictates when the rendering is done. My opinion is that the latter is better. Your application should be arranged so that only the view itself knows when it should be rendered (should it be right after initialization or fetching a model/collection). I do not see ANY problems in calling `render` within `initialize`, even though `delegateEvents` is called after it. Populating `el` shouldn't make any difference with how it functions.

Calling `render` within `initialize` is a good practice, because it works regardless of the situation and unifies the way you do render (you'll adding views that render after fetch the same way as other views). I haven't run into any problems doing rendering this way yet and apparently you haven't either!

Hope this helps (or helps to reassure you)!

Comment: When it comes to writing unit tests, having a render call in initialize can be a huge pain.  Consider that every test might construct the view to test against one of its methods, if that view is then attempting to render you need to either 1) mock out that render every time, or 2) align things so that render won't break anything.  In either case, not something you want to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

"...long time back i sort of was convinced myself that render() is prerogative of view itself and not parent views concern."

You were on the right track. While people often treat `render` like a public method, you will find that calling render from outside the view will lead to nothing but spaghetti code and chaos.

The best practice is to render (or schedule a render) as part of initialization, and in response to the appropriate events on the relevant models.